# ClassCastException during JUnit

Tags: java, junit

this is my code

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("from " + Applicazione.class.getName() +" a where a.id = :id");
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    Applicazione applicazione = (Applicazione) query.getSingleResult();
```

It's very simple. But I don't understand why during JUnit Test the method getSingleResult() raise a classcast exception...

- Same Context (more context same class can be provide this ex)
- Check SerialID

Why happen?!?!

Thanks

**UPDATE** 
This is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
it.xxxxx.intranet.core.model.Applicazione cannot be cast to 
it.xxxxx.intranet.core.model.Applicazione

java.lang.ClassCastException: it.XXXX.intranet.core.model.Applicazione cannot be cast to it.XXXX.intranet.core.model.Applicazione
    at it.xxxxx.intranet.core.dao.impl.ApplicazioneDaoImpl.findApplicazioneById(ApplicazioneDaoImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy16.findApplicazioneById(Unknown Source)
    at it.xxxxx.intranet.core.service.impl.ApplicazioneServiceImpl.findApplicazioneById(ApplicazioneServiceImpl.java:25)
    at it.xxxxx.intranet.core.test.GestioneApplicazioniTest.detailApplicazioneTest(GestioneApplicazioniTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The line :40 is `Applicazione applicazione = (Applicazione) query.getSingleResult();`

Comment: can you update the post with exact stacktrace? and what is the type of `Query` ? in `org.hibernate.Query` I dont see `getSingleResult()` method.

Comment: Hi.. It's javax.persistence.query

Comment: a stacktrace will help SO users give quick accurate answer!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have imported wrong `Applicazione` in your class (Since you have class name as same, I am assuming they are in different packages).

Check the `import` statement for `Applicazione` and fix it.

**EDIT:**

I just observed that you are using `"from " + Applicazione.class.getName() +" a where a.id = :id"` string. So if your query is returning result, even the assignment should work (without Exception) 
Cause you can't have simple name specified for 2 different package classes with same name, and one of them should have fully qualified class name . Are you sure you have posted the right code?

Comment: Just checked... There is one and only one.. mmm

Comment: Are you sure about the stacktrace? your stacktrace conveys that you are casting 2 different classes

Comment: I agree with you. But I have one project (Spring Based) with models, dao and services. The model refer a Oracle table that extends Persistable<Long>. Have the serialID (to ensure the uniqueness of the object). Or it's a really stupid thing or a bug. Yes, I've posted the right code.